# Java: large startup overhead of external application - ProcessBuilder, NuProcess, Zt-Exec

Tags: java, performance, process

I am starting command line applications from Java. The problem is that starting application from a command line takes much less time than from Java. I heave read various StackOverflow questions similar to mine (for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943431/execute-an-external-command-in-java), [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655651/efficient-execution-and-output-stream-redirection-of-process-spawned-with-runtim)). They complain on the overhead inherent to Java and suggest various approaches to reduce startup overhead. Unfortunately, they do not report back whether they have really reached an improvement.

I have tried several approaches without success. I would like to hear what I am doing wrong. I will not provide slow code for ProcessBuilder.

[NuProcess library](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess):

```
    NuProcessBuilder pb = new NuProcessBuilder(params);
    pb.setCwd(Paths.get(inputFilePath));

    ProcessHandler handler = new ProcessHandler();
    pb.setProcessListener(handler);

    NuProcess process = pb.start();
    process.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

[Zt-Exec library](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec) (uses ProcessBuilder internally):

```
    String output =
            new ProcessExecutor()
                    .command(params)
                    .readOutput(true)
                    .timeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .exitValue(0)
                    .directory(new File(inputFilePath))
                    .execute()
                    .outputUTF8();
```

I did not try [this native lib](https://github.com/axiak/java_posix_spawn/) since I saw the question that reported no improvement.

I reach only 2.476 seconds instead of only 869 ms running from command line. This is very critical for my application. These numbers are for Windows 10. I have carried out tests on Linux Ubuntu and got approx. the same ratio.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I am currently having the same problem in a project and we have tried multiple different things and analyzed the problem in multiple different ways, without success. I have opened a Github Issue on the Docker for Mac Repository, if it still may be of any help to you: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6401

Comment: Hi Felix, I have not found a solution to this problem.